# Does RPM automatically retry failed download attempts?

Tags: bash, rpm, ibm-unix-system-services

My particular situation isn't on a Linux box, rather an IBM i.  But I'm running RPM within a BASH shell and attempted to download and install nano using RPM - it failed.  I didn't think anything of it, but now I'm noticing authority failures to the RPM download directory whenever I restart my web server instance.

I'm pulling at strings by now, but my best guess is that RPM is attempting to retry the failed download/install every time I restart the web server instance.  I understand IBM i and Linux are different, but from a Linux standpoint, Does RPM automatically retry failed download/install attempts?  If not, does it do anything in the event of a failed download/install beyond an error message stating it failed?

**Note***: I really don't think RPM requires a web server to function, but like I said I'm just pulling on any string I can think of at the moment.

Comment: yum downloads, but rpm doesn't...

Comment: Okay thanks, so RPM just installs the packages YUM downloads?  Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I forgot to tag you.  If you post an answer I'll accept.

Comment: @ThomasDickey RPM actually _can_ work on remote packages directly. Try (non-invasive — it's just a query) `rpm -qip https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/24/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/f/fedora-release-24-1.noarch.rpm` and see. Given the unclear context here (rpm from a bash script) that _could_ be the case.